# Latexmk and the location of Asymptote's generated files

Tags: asymptote, latexmk

I am trying out Asymptote with latexmk and I would like to automate the interaction.

Consider the following latex document `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\def\asydir{asymptote}

\begin{document}

Testing Asymptote:

\begin{asy}
settings.outformat = "pdf";
unitsize(2cm);
draw((0,0) -- (1,0));
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

In my `latexmkrc` I have the [following lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208750/latexmkrc-asymptote-and-subfolders-on-mac-os) for Asymptote integration:

```
sub asy {return system("asy -o asymptote/ \"$_[0]\"");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

Running `latexmk -pdf test.tex` generates `test.pdf` in the current folder and `test-1.asy` and `test-1.pdf` in the `asymptote` folder -- but only if

- I manually created the `asymptote` folder prior to running `latexmk`.
- The folder specification in the latex document (`\def\asydir{asymptote}`) and `latexmkrc` (`-o asymptote/`) are identical.

I would like `latexmk` to read `asydir` from the main tex file, create the directory if it does not exist and run `asy` with the read output folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change the `sub asy` line in `latexmrc` to

```
sub asy {return system("asy -o \"$_[0]\" \"$_[0]\"");}
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't answer the stated question at all, does it? If `asymptote/` folder doesn't exist in the first place then it won't be created.