# Asymptote Files

Tags: asymptote

Whenever I use Asymptote with Latex, each instance of the environment gets its own new file. This creates a large amount of files. Is there any way to get all of these files placed into another folder by themselves?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Latexmk and the location of Asymptote's generated files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258103/latexmk-and-the-location-of-asymptotes-generated-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [dtx file](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/blob/master/doc/asy-latex.dtx#L95):

```
% This package produces quite a number of output files, which by default
% are created in the same directory as the \LaTeX\ document that is being
% compiled. To keep things more tidy, you can specify an output directory
% for these files by defining the \cmd\asydir\ command. For example, if you
% wish to store the figure files in the subdirectory \texttt{asytmp/}, the
% you would write \verb|\renewcommand\asydir{asytmp}|.
%
% Alternatively (and tentatively), you may write \verb|dir=asytmp| in
% either the \texttt{asy} environment options or the options to
% \cmd\asysetup.
```

Alternatively, from [`asy-latex.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/asymptote/doc/asy-latex.pdf):

> This package produces quite a number of output files, which by default
>   are created in the same directory as the LATEX document that is being
>   compiled. To keep things more tidy, you can specify an output
>   directory for these files by defining the `\asydir` command. For
>   example, if you wish to store the figure files in the subdirectory
>   `asytmp/`, the you would write `\renewcommand\asydir{asytmp}`.
>
> Alternatively (and tentatively), you may write `dir=asytmp` in either
>   the `asy` environment options or the options to `\asysetup`.

So far as I know this information is not found in `asymptote.pdf`, the main documentation for Asymptote.

Comment: After using this, I came upon another problem: asymptote cannot find the files in the subdirectory. For example, if I used `\renewcommand\asydir{asyfiles}`, and tried `asy.exe asyfiles/[filename]-*.asy`, it cannot find the `.asy` files. How would I fix this?

Comment: The most likely fix is simply to `cd` to `asyfiles` before running `asy.exe`. If that is unsatisfactory, I'm not sure. Since you are apparently using Windows, make sure you are using `\` rather than `/` to denote directory change. If that is fixed in the real comment, the error I would predict is that `asy.exe` successfully compiles the files, but puts the images in the document's root folder rather than in the `asyfiles` subfolder. If `asy.exe` is in fact not finding the files, I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Dear Charles, How do I get the following to work? the way I wrote doesn't change the directory for me.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asypictureB,asymptote}
\asysetup{dir=tmp}%doesn't work
\renewcommand\asydir{tmp}%doesn't work
\begin{asyheader}
\end{asyheader}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{}
unitsize(1cm);
draw((0,0)--(1,1));
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}