# output directory Asymptote in TeXLive

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, asymptote, output, folders

How does the `asymptote` and `asypictureB` packages determine the output file and working directories? I tried to use `asypictureB` and TeXLive to produce my files and put all the output files to a different directory.  For pdflatex, this can be done by the `-output-directory=dir option`, and the `*.asy` files are in the dir folder.  but then `asy.exe` cannot find this file.  I tried to let TeX know the working directory by following this post: [Asymptote Files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312944/asymptote-files)
and tried all the options

```
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\asydir{asytmp}
\asysetup{dir= xxx}
\begin{asypicture}{}
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

none of them seemed to affect the working directory.  I also tried to use TexStudio to change the asymptote command to be `asy.exe dir/filename.asy`, or include the `-cd dir after asy.exe`, but none of these work.  asy.exe keeps searching for the files under the current directory.

Under mac, I found a workaround by revising the pdflatex command in TexStudio to include a series of bash commands:

```
sh -c "cp %.tex ~/asytmp/%.tex
& cd ~/asytmp/ && pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode 
%.tex
&& cd - && cp ~/asytmp/%.pdf %.pdf
&& cd ~/asytmp && find . \! -name '1' -delete"
```

but when I followed the same way and tried under Windows by using
`cmd /C "... | ... | ..."`  it does not work because the `cd dir` command doesn't work under windows and everything seems to be still executed under the current directory.

any thoughts on how to get this to work?  Is it possible to revise the `~/.asy/config.asy` file?  I don't even know if the asymptote and asypictureB packages use this config file.

Comment: First note: the `asypictureB` package does not allow you to change the working directory. The `asymptote` package does (using `\asydir`). Second note: You might find this helpful: https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/e35300dd/

Answer (score 0):

I tried again and the `/asydir` command seems to interfere with how pdflatex proccesses the `*.asy` file and I got the error "cannot write on the file `dir/*-noname-1.asy`".

It turns out that the workaround in MacOS described above works in windows.  just need to keep using "&" instead of "|" between the different codes.

```
cmd /C "@echo off && pushd .
&& copy %.tex C:\localtexmf\tmp\%.tex & cd C:\localtexmf\tmp
&& pdflatex.exe --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
&& asy.exe *.asy
&& pdflatex.exe --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
&& popd
&& copy C:\localtexmf\tmp\%.pdf %.pdf"
| txs:///view
```

**NOTE:** I formatted these codes to be multi-lines for readability, but it should be made sure that all the things are written in one line in TeXStudio.